# invalid FEN in PGN viewer crashes your browser

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

I was modifying a FEN inside my question, as soon as I made a change (which made the FEN invalid), my web browser went in not-responding mode and after 30 secs it asked me *"a heavy script is running, bla bla, Do you want to stop it from running?"*.

After stopping the script, I think it made me wait another 30 sec, then the page suffered irreversible damage and did not work properly until I performed a refresh.

I believe it is possible to make some changes to the code so that it doesn't crash like this, important drafts might get lost in the process.

**Details:**

- I was modifying a FEN `[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]`
- Using FireFox 17.0.1

Comment: Also happening with chromium, ask some chat of mine with Andrews for more details, iirc.

Comment: This seems to be resolved?